# How to get xpath using beautifulsoup after we find a tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried beautifulsoup to get a list of elements and then I want the xpath so that I can click it, the button that I want to click is arbitrary it can be anywhere depending on the data.

Eg.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup=bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser') #used selenium
soup.find('div', class_='dataTable').find_all('span',class_='blue-icon')
```

Class name can be anything I just made up one but I want to know the main thing how can I get the xpath.
It gave me a list of two span tags actually these span tags are a button that can be anywhere in the table and sometimes they won't so I want to if I can use it to find it's xpath so that I can use selenium to click the button whenever I see this span tag.
If you want to have a look at the website:
https://www.screener.in/company/GRANULES/consolidated/
Now there are some tables that have plus (+) symbol after clicking it it gives extra info so I want to scrape that too, but without clicking it I can't scrape it, so this is the method I thought of but I could not get to locate the symbol.
If anyone can help me with this. There can be any other methods to do this that would help too.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you manually try to click the buttons using javascript in the browser console, sometimes the HTML elements appear then. Almost everything can be controlled this way.

Comment: Did you try the given code?

Comment: @QHarr yes I did and it did work though but I wanted like there were more than 1 '+' symbol like this so I wanted to click all of them at once and then I used driver.find_all_elements and the common attribute to all such as the button tag's class sl it worked and it clicked all the symbols so then I could scrape the tables then I used pd.read_html but it did not scrape the rows that got revealed by the symbol so I did it using beautifulsoup soup then all the tr tags were scraped. I was busy this whole time so I couldn't get a chance to thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clicking buttons:**

To interact with the buttons you need to automate a browser e.g. with selenium.

---

**Targeting a specific button:**

You will notice the expand + buttons have an `onclick` attribute which triggers a function call with various arguments. It may be possible to replicate this with `requests`; However, I am going to focus on the fact you can target the particular + button by that attribute, and its value, based upon the unique arguments, passed to the function, using a [css attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector with * contains operator.

You can see here the function that is called with `Expenses` and `Quarters` arguments in line with the part of the table to be expanded:

[image]

I target that onclick attribute by the argument values, escaping the ' as I wrapping with outer '. I am looking for the onclick containing those values.

---

**Expand all +**

To find all + buttons, rather than target a specific one, change the method call to `find_elements_by_css_selector` and change the css selector to instead look at the function rather than the arguments i.e. `[onclick*="Company.showSchedule"]`.

You will need to loop the matched webElements collection (list) to click individual elements within the loop.

---

**Py:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.screener.in/company/GRANULES/consolidated/')
d.find_element_by_css_selector('[onclick*="\'Expenses\', \'quarters\'"]').click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked but I needed all the buttons to be clicked at once and I got it. But my actual question was that can I like get a full xpath or something when I use beautifulsoup like soup.find('div', class_='blue-icon') can I get full xpath or xpath using this, this was my question. Thanks for your help again.